# How to set array key to null if it does not exist?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example i have an array:

```
array(
    'a' => 'value',
    'b' => 'value',
    'c',
    'd' => 'value',
    'e' => array(
        'f' => 'value',
        'g',
        array(
            'h' => 'value',
            'i'
        )
    ),
    'k',
    'l' => 'value'
);
```

I need recursively walk trough it and set key to NULL if it doesn't exists like this:

```
array(
    'a' => 'value',
    'b' => 'value',
    NULL => 'c',
    'd' => 'value',
    'e' => array(
        'f' => 'value',
        NULL => 'g',
        array(
            'h' => 'value',
            NULL => 'i'
        )
    ),
    NULL => 'k',
    'l' => 'value'
);
```

**UPDATE**
I need this because i need to encode array in `JSON` and push to browser. The problem is that the `json_encode` sets key to 0 if it not exists, but if there is `NULL` it also remains the same in browser. So when i using this array in JS, i can detect where is the real 0 and where 0 was created because there was no key.

Comment: You can't have `NULL` as a key, nor can you have duplicate array keys.  Why not set the *value* to `NULL`?  (ps: `array('a'=> 'value', 'b')`  will create: `array('a'=> 'value', 0 => 'b')`)  There is no such thing as a "non-existent" key.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: you cant have NULL keys, only NULL values

Comment: From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) _Null will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key null will actually be stored under ""._

Comment: @dbf exactly. This means that you set it to "", even when you can put NULL into it. I say there can't be NULL keys, when, after inserting are still NULL's visible.

Comment: But why do you want to set the key to NULL? Do you want to unset it?

Comment: @RocketHazmat updated my post, please look once more...

Comment: @user1692333: `where array key not exists`.  There is no such thing as a "non-existent" key.  The keys are auto-assigned if left out.  `json_encode` doesn't set anything.  PHP does when you make the array.

Comment: @yes, sorry for misprint. But it doesn't change situation in general. If key is set to NULL - it remains NULL in JSON. No other solution for this...

Comment: there are an infinite (ok not really) number of non existent keys

Comment: @user1692333: There's no way to do what you want.  It's impossible.  There is no way to detect that PHP auto-added a key vs you assigning the key.  The best you can do is, in JavaScript if the key is numeric then you can *assume* it was auto-added by PHP.  But you cannot detect if PHP auto-added a key.  If you type `array(0 => 'a', 'b')` you will get `array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b')`.

Comment: @user1692333 let's assume `NULL` can be set, then still this approach will fail if multiple keys have to be `NULL`, array keys are _unique identifiers_ .. again from the very same [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php): _If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten._

Comment: A better solution for this would seem to be assigning array indexes explicitly, so you don't have this case of an auto-indexed 0 vs an index of 0 that your code assigned explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The keys do exist, they are just automatically assigned and are numeric. From [`Arrays`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> The key is optional. If it is not specified, PHP will use the increment of the largest previously used integer key.

You cannot detect, if the numeric key was assigned explicitly or if the key was just omitted. You can do this only at the time when the array is created or the value is appended to the array. Afterwards, you can only replace numeric keys with some other value.

Additionally

> If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.

This means, you cannot replace *missing* keys with `NULL`, but only one of them. If you set multiple keys to `NULL`, every assignment will delete the previous `NULL` key/value pair.

And finally

> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> - Null will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key null will actually be stored under "".

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_walk_recursive`.

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value, &$key) {
    $value = NULL; /* for example as you cannot use multiple NULL-keys nor set the key to NULL... */
});
```

P.s.: For an explanation *why* you cannot use NULL-keys, see the post of @OlafDietsche